# PIL ImageDraw.Draw() doesn't work when used in a function

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, mandelbrot

I made a program that renders the Mandelbrot set to an image. I put the draw.point() method in a function, but it doesn't seem to actually draw on the final image, but if I put im.save() in the function it does work. The full code actually uses multiprocessing and renders the image CineBench style, which is why I can't put the im.save() in the function, or pull the draw.point() out of it. Is there some other way I can solve the problem?

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


im = Image.new("RGB", (hor_res, vert_res), (0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)


def mandelbrot():
    # mandelbrot code


def box_renderer(x_start: int, x_end: int, y_start: int, y_end: int):
    for y in range(y_start, y_end):
        for x in range(x_start, x_end):
             colour = 255 - int(255*mandelbrot(x, y)/iterations)
             draw.point([x, y], (0, 0, colour))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    box_renderer(args)
    im.save("mandelbrot.png", "PNG")
```

This is not the entire program, but hopefully enough to make sense

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your sample code is representative, because this version works fine:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

hor_res, vert_res = 200, 200
im = Image.new("RGB", (hor_res, vert_res), (255, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

def box_renderer(x_start: int, x_end: int, y_start: int, y_end: int):
    for y in range(y_start, y_end):
        for x in range(x_start, x_end):
             colour = 128
             draw.point([x, y], (0, 0, colour))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    box_renderer(x_start=50,x_end=100,y_start=20,y_end=180)
    im.save("mandelbrot.png", "PNG")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I agree, I only found out after making this post that multiprocessing was messing with it. What I'm trying to do now is have each process create its own image object which it will return for stitching together globlally